# AngularJS how to handle a Bootstrap datepicker date to send it out for a REST backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I have a angular-strap bootstrap datepicker

```
<input id="dp5" class="span8" type="text" ng-model="obj.date" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"  placeholder="Pick a Date" bs-datepicker>
```

The backend is a Spring MVC REST application which originally returns the date in milliseconds (java.util.Date). The date I receive from the above datepicker element is in the following format

```
2013-10-01T06:00:00.000Z
```

How can I convert it to milliseconds so that I can properly ship it to the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know you can create directive to handle it:

Demo <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rhALf7Ot2ieQgQPpIWWE?p=preview)</kbd>

```
app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR'
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {

            var outputDate = new Date(e.date);

           var n = outputDate.getTime();


           ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(n);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

And HTML wrapper for date-picker should be like:

```
  <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
```

So after date change `var1` gets milliseconds (see Demo)

Hope this direction will help

Answer (score 4):

You can call `Date.parse` function on the string:

```
Date.parse("2013-10-01T06:00:00.000Z") // 1380607200000
```